# Symfony2 get logged in user instance from custom User class

Tags: symfony

I have my own custom User class implementing the UserInterface. A snippet follows:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=30, unique=true)
 */
protected $username;

...

 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
...
```

In one controller, I want to be able to load the current logged in user. I do it as follows:

```
$user_id = NULL;
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))        
        $user_obj = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

         $user_id = $this->getUser()->getId(); //This yields an exception!
         $user_obj->getUsername(); // This works!

    }
```

I can do a getUsername(), it returns the adequate username. However, if I try a getId() it does not work. It yields the following exception:

```
Attempted to call method "getId" on class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User
```

Is there an easy way for me to be able to getId() from this object?

Comment: It looks like you don't use your own User class but Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Med pointed out, it is using the default Symfony2 User class. You need to define your own [user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and register your class with the security context.